# componentWillReceiveProps not being called if 2 different prop changes have the same values

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react component that needs to do some computing on its WillReceiveProps state. This is what the component looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Message from './Message.react'

class MessageContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {show: false, message: null}
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.message) {
      this.setState({show: true});
      setTimeout(
        () => {
          this.setState({show: false})
        },
        5000);
    }
  }

  render() {
    let message = this.props.message;

    return (message ? <Message message={message} show={this.state.show}/> : null)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
  return {
    message: state.message
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(MessageContainer);
```

The idea is that if a String prop called 'message' changes, then we should show the component and after 5 seconds we should hide it.

It work correctly except that if for some reason, the new message is the same value that the last (for instance "Item successfully added") **componentWillReceiveProps** is not being called, which means the component is not shown.

How do I handle this situation? I'm open to clear the props but I'm not sure where to do that.

Comment: Did you put a console.log in there to verify that it doesn't run at all?
If you're sure that it doesn't run at all, then maybe your component is being unmounted. And when you want it there again, it needs to completely mount again, which makes it run componentWillMount() instead of willReceiveProps(), which only happens on updates.... I don't know why that would be the case, but I'm not sure how else this can be explained. Maybe you could you post code on how your component is  being used?

Comment: Yes I did debug and added console.log(). I'm pretty sure it's not being called. And about it being unmounted, I don't think it's the case because if the message is different, it works just fine. The problem is always when the message is the same as the last.

Comment: Can you verify that in the component above, (the one that's using the component in question), that render() is actually called when you set a message that's the same as the last? If you implemented shouldComponentUpdate() on the component above, and then you change the state with the intention of passing the message as a prop to the child, it won't even call render() if the state hasn't changed... and hence your child doesn't even update

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that I'm using redux and that what is passing the prop is not a upper component but rather the redux framework. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so I remember something about redux implementing componentShouldUpdate by default... I'll verify in a bit, but I remember it biting me in the *** when I wrapped a Route with redux lol. Although in this case I guess it's a bit different because you're not passing anything to a redux wrapped component. For now, maybe set a dummy redux state that'll toggle back and forth whenever you update redux state. It's a long shot but maybe it'll work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're connecting your component to redux with connect(), your exported component is actually a high order component which implements `shouldComponentUpdate` (SCU) internally for you by react-redux binding. (similar to `React.PureComponent`).

Your connected component only need to pass down single state prop `state.message` (no dispatchProps and ownProps), as long as it remains unchanged, SCU returns **false**, your connected component will *not* rerender, thus your componentWillReceiveProps don't get called.

You can turn off the default optimization by passing a config object to the 4th parameter as follow and your componentWillReceiveProps should get called as you expected.

```
connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    null, 
    null,
   { pure: false }
)
```

Comment: Glad you don't step into the mud, dude :]